# Generic type inference with multiply-implemented covariant interfaces, how to work around it?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, covariance

Consider this silly program that does nothing:

```
interface I<out T> { }
class A1 : I<A1> { }
class A2 : A1, I<A2> { }
class B1 { }
class B2 : B1, I<B2> { }
class C1 : I<A1> { }
class C2 : C1, I<A2> { }

static class Program
{
    static void f<T>(I<T> obj)
    {
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        f<A1>(new A2());
        f<A2>(new A2());
        f<B1>(new B2());
        f<B2>(new B2());
        f<A1>(new C2());
        f<A2>(new C2());
    }
}
```

This shows that `A2` and `C2` implement both `I<A1>` and `I<A2>`, and that `B2` implements both `I<B1>` and `I<B2>`.

However, modifying this to

```
static void Main()
{
    f(new A2());
    f(new B2());
    f(new C2());
}
```

shows that on the first and third lines, `f`'s generic type argument cannot be inferred from the passed argument, yet on the second line, it can be.

I understand what it is that the compiler is doing here, so that doesn't need explaining. But how can I work around this? Is there some way to modify this so that I *can* define the interface on both the base and the derived class, yet have type inference work when passing the derived class?

What I had in mind was to look for a way to "hide" a base class's implemented interfaces, so that the compiler doesn't see them and use them, even though they do exist. However, C# doesn't seem to provide an option to do so.

*Clarification*: in my silly example program, `A1` implements `I` with itself as the generic type argument. I do have that in my real code, but I also have classes that implement `I` with a different generic type argument, and have added `C1` and `C2` to my example code for that reason.

Comment: Curious: Why don't you prefer not to specify type parameter?

Comment: Is this a situation you've run into? I can't think of a case where you'd have a classes implementing an interface with their own type as a covariant parameter. Contravariant, yes (e.g. in `CompareTo`).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I do prefer not to specify the type parameter. I'm a firm believer in letting the computer do as much of my work as possible. :)

Comment: @BenAaronson Yes, it is. The interface provides a way to obtain an instance of the type argument, and would be a simple `return this;` if a class `C` implements `I<C>` directly, but `D` might also implement `I<C>` if proxy-like objects are used.

Comment: @BenAaronson Some callers merely have an `I<A2>` variable, and those callers don't know whether they're dealing with a proxy. Others do have a real `A2` variable. If possible, I'd like it the call to `f` to automatically work for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using two F variants (second one just for type inference that calls the other) and an "override" interface J inheriting from I which does nothing it could be done like so:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;


interface I<out T>
{
    void Print();
}

interface J<out T> : I<T> { }

class A : I<C>
{
    void I<C>.Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A: I<C>");
    }
}

class B {}

class C : B { }

class D1 : I<A>
{
    void I<A>.Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("D1: I<A>");
    }
}

class D2 : D1, J<B>
{
    void I<B>.Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("D2: I<B>");
    }
}

class D3 : D1, J<C>
{
    void I<C>.Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("D3: I<C>");
    }
}

class D4 : A, J<B>
{
    void I<B>.Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("D4: I<B>");
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void f<T>(J<T> obj)
    {
        f((I<T>)obj);
    }

    static void f<T>(I<T> obj)
    {
        obj.Print();
    }

    static void Main()
    {

        f<A>(new D2());
        f(new D2());

        f(new D3());

        f(new D4());
        f<C>(new D4());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
D1: I<A>
D2: I<B>
D3: I<C>
D4: I<B>
A: I<C>
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach. If I'm understanding you correctly though, if I want to derive from a class that implements `J<X>`, it wouldn't work: the derived class would have to implement `J<Y>`, and then the call to `f` would be ambiguous again. But that could be resolved by a third generic interface `K`, and so on. The only problem would be in managing the interfaces: it would be very easy to forget to update the implemented interfaces if I change the nesting from two-deep to three-deep. Perhaps I could automate that, and if so, that would make your approach the best so far, IMO.

Comment: Thats true for every level of inheritance another interface required like IOverrideLevelX. And another polymorph of f function for that interface.

Comment: I hadn't accepted this answer yet because I been busy with other projects, so I haven't actually got it working yet, but it'll take longer before I get back on that project. Let me tentatively accept it. I can always unaccept if it turns out unworkable. :)

Answer (score 1):

Lambda expressions may sometimes be helpful in selecting Generic argument type. This is a little convoluted way, but it let your A1 and A2 classes to decide, which interface would be chosen in the f2 call:

```
interface IChooseGenericArg<T>
{
    T Choose();
}

interface I<out T> 
{
    string M1();
}
class A1 : I<A1>, IChooseGenericArg<A1>
{
    public string M1()
    {
        return "A1.M1";
    }
    public A1 Choose()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
class A2 : A1, I<A2>, IChooseGenericArg<A2>
{
    public string M1()
    {
        return "A2.M1";
    }

    public new A2 Choose()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
static class Program
{
    static void f<T>(I<T> obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.M1());
    }

    static void f2<T>(Func<T> selector, I<T> obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.M1());
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        f<A1>(new A1());
        f<A2>(new A2());

        var a2 = new A2();
        f2(() => a2.Choose(), a2);
        var a1 = new A1();
        f2(() => a1.Choose(), a1);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually surprisingly similar to something I've already come up with (and have now posted as an answer, for reference). The form you're using doesn't allow `class C2 : C1, I<A2> { public new A2 { return this; } }`, because `C2` and `A2` are incompatible, but your idea is essentially the same as mine.

Comment: BTW, your answer doesn't actually make use of the `IChooseGenericArg<T>` interface, and it wouldn't work if you do change it to make use of it, so I think you can just remove that part of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, here's the best I've come up with. I don't really like it that much, but I have kept it as a least-bad option, for when reworking the code to avoid a need for this doesn't work.

```
interface I<out T> { }
class A1 : I<A1> {
  public I<A1> PreferredInterface
  { get { return this; } }
}
class A2 : A1, I<A2> {
  public new I<A2> PreferredInterface
  { get { return this; } }
}
class B1 { }
class B2 : B1, I<B2> {
  public I<B2> PreferredInterface
  { get { return this; } }
}
class C1 : I<A1> {
  public I<A1> PreferredInterface
  { get { return this; } }
}
class C2 : C1, I<A2> {
  public new I<A2> PreferredInterface
  { get { return this; } }
}

static class Program
{
    static void f<T>(I<T> obj)
    {
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        f<A1>(new A2().PreferredInterface);
        f<A2>(new A2().PreferredInterface);
        f<B1>(new B2().PreferredInterface);
        f<B2>(new B2().PreferredInterface);
        f<A1>(new C2().PreferredInterface);
        f<A2>(new C2().PreferredInterface);
        f(new A2().PreferredInterface);
        f(new B2().PreferredInterface);
        f(new C2().PreferredInterface);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the signature of `f` and using a generic constraint to effectively get similar behavior within `f`:

```
static void f<T>( T obj ) where T : I<T>
{
}
```

It's difficult to tell if this will actually allow you to accomplish what you want, however. This also won't work for types like `C2` below:

```
class C1 : I<C1> { }
class C2 : C1 { }
```

If you need to be able to handle these cases, I think I'd have to recommend just specifying the type arguments explicitly.  I can't think of a way around this.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I should have edited my question. I explained in the comments on the question that I can also have classes like `class D : I<C>` (which doesn't even derive from `C`). Thanks for the suggestion though, it could easily have been useful in similar code.